# What is the minimum OS for binaries created with VS2010?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010

This might sound like a stupid question, but I'm asking because my boss wants to know. What is the minimum Windows OS for binaries created with Visual Studio 2010? Not all the developers on the team have the Windows SDK installed. I know with it you can target down to Windows XP, but any idea what you can target without Windows SDK?

Comment: You cannot target anything without the Windows SDK.  If they have Visual Studio then they also have the SDK.  Cannot otherwise answer your question without knowing the language and libraries you use.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you set WINVER in any header file before the core window.h is included, this determines which OS is required by the binary.

Comment: What if you don't add that, what would the minimum be?

Comment: I don't know what the min is, but you should see some message in the output window saying "WINVER not defined, assuming ###".

Answer (score 1):

**Visual Studio 2005**

- Windows 98, Windows 98 Second Edition
- Windows Millennium Edition
- Windows 2000
- Windows XP
- Windows Server 2003

**Visual Studio 2008**

- Windows 2000
- Windows XP
- Windows Server 2003
- Windows Vista

**Visual Studio 2010**

- Windows XP
- Windows Server 2003
- Windows Vista
- Windows Server 2008
- Windows 7
- Windows Server 2008 R2

**Visual Studio 2012**

- Windows XP
- Windows Server 2003
- Windows Vista
- Windows Server 2008
- Windows 7
- Windows Server 2012 R2
- Windows 8

From:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms235435.aspx

**And for history's sake:**

- VC6 for Win95, NT 3 & 4, Win2K and other older operating systems
- Use Visual C++ 1.52 or Microsoft QuickC for 16-bit or DOS